# Copy XtraTreeList to another treelist

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist

I have a collection of TreeListNodes. I am doing this to copy all nodes to another tree.

```
foreach (TreeListNode tn in nodes)
                trTree.Nodes.Add(tn);
```

Above code works, but expand-collapse of nodes in tree won't work after this.

How can I copy one XtraTreelist to another ?

Answer (score 1):

It will not work this way, you are *sharing nodes* between trees with same memory location. Think about if you change data on Tree 1, it will affect immediately to Tree 2.

It would be suggested to do *Deep Copy* on `TreeListNode` with `DeepClone` method:

```
public static class CloneHelper
{
    public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;

            return (T) formatter.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
var cloneNodes = nodes.Select(node => CloneHelper.DeepClone<TreeListNode>(node))
                      .ToArray();

trTree.Nodes.AddRange(cloneNodes);
```

**Edit:**

Of course you need to make sure `TreeListNode` is marked as [Serializale]

Another approach, you need to re-build the second tree with the data used in the first tree

Comment: Tried your approach, but I am getting this error: Type 'DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode' in Assembly 'DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v11.1, Version=11.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' is not marked as serializable

Comment: @buffer_overflow: well in that case, you need to re-build tree 2, or copy each properties of node in tree 1